# XNA: How to get the BackBuffer RenderTarget

Tags: c#, xna, directx

in XNA, I need to get a reference to the `RenderTarget`(2D) of the `BackBuffer` in order to draw it to a texture or change its `Usage` to `Usage.PreserveContents`, is there any method which allows me to do that?

Comment: Could you just change your drawing code to draw to a texture that has preserve contents, then draw that to the backbuffer each frame? That should be faster. I vaguely remember that in XNA 4.0 it's pretty slow to get the backbuffer texture (if you can at all).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/03/30/resolvebackbuffer-and-resolvetexture2d-in-xna-game-studio-4-0.aspx) about what happened to `ResolveBackBuffer` in XNA 4.0.

Basically, you should just use render targets.

If you *really* need the back-buffer, you can use `GetBackBufferData`. But it only works on the HiDef profile.

If you need to change the `RenderTargetUsage` of the back-buffer, you need to respond to `PreparingDeviceSettings` and modify `GraphicsDeviceInformation.PresentationParameters.RenderTargetUsage`. (This was explained in [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2007/11/21/rendertarget-changes-in-xna-game-studio-2-0.aspx).)

Note that changing this away from the default is not recommended. The correct solution is to fix the order in which you set and draw to your render targets.