# How to set pixels in Monogame opengl?

Tags: c#, opengl, pixel

I am new to Opengl I just got it today with the Monogame download for visual studio. I would like know how i could change hundreds of thousands of pixels then display them? what is the fastest way?

```
protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
{
    GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);
    //I would like to do something like this
    for (int x = 0; x <= 600; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y <= 600; y++)
            {
                //setpixel(x,y) = 255,0,0;
            } 
        }

    base.Draw(gameTime);
}
```

It came with this code so im guessing I should do it here.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8464120/xna-how-to-get-the-backbuffer-rendertarget). I think you can get an array of pixels by using `GraphicsDevice.GetBackBufferData (T[])` as well. Setting values in an array would be faster than calling a function, but I'm not sure if this is the way to do it. Something like `pixels[26] = 0xff00ff` would be faster than `SetPixel(5, 3, 0xff00ff)`.